# How to "relax" wcf transport security

Tags: wcf, transport-security, wcf-wshttpbinding

I wonder if exists some magic configuration parameter to "relax" WCF SecurityMode=Transport in order to use it with no SSL(http instead of https).
I need to setup (for testing purpose) a wsHttpBinding with UserName credentials under http.
I understand the underlying requirements, but I just need it for easy testing purpose.

Comment: I think you could only set WCF SecurityMode = TransportCredentialOnly, you also have to enable basic authentication in IIS. http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx

Comment: I'm going to try TransportWithMessageCredential http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185295/wcf-authentication-transportcredentialonly-with-aspnet-membership TransportCredentialOnly seems to work only  for httpBinding. Thanks anyway for the tips, that might gonna put me onto the right track!

Comment: It seems there's no workaround for ssl using wsHttpBinding